# Computing the derivative of a determinant expression

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to compute the derivative of the function $f(t)=\det(tC+I)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. I know the answer should be $tr(C)$ but I am struggling to find an easy way to see this. Some suggestions I have received are using the Leibniz rule for determinants and I am interested if there is a way to do it using the Jacobi formula.

Comment: "derivative" with respect to what?

Comment: With respect to the variable t, a real number. I should have made this more explicit.

Comment: Agreed.  In fact, you should Edit your Question to either give your function a name, for example , "$f(t) = \dots$" which will implicitly specify what is intended to be the independent variable, or state with respect to which variable you intend the derivative.

Comment: the answer is $tr(C)$ only for $t=0$

Answer (score 2):

You can write: $$\det(tC+I)= t^n\det(C + \frac{1}{t} I) = t^nP_{(-C)}(\frac{1}{t})$$ where $P_{A}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. From this you can see that the polynomial coefficients of $t^nP_{(-C)}(\frac{1}{t})$ are the coefficients of $P_{(-C)}$ written in reverse order. We get:

$$t^nP_{(-C)}(\frac{1}{t}) = 1 + tr(C)t \cdots + \det(C)t^n$$

As $\det(C)$ is the bottom coefficient of $P_{(-C)}$, it is the top coefficient of $t^nP_{(-C)}(\frac{1}{t})$.

From this we see that the derivative in $t$ of $$\det(tC+I) = 1 + tr(C)t + \cdots +\det(C)t^n$$ is $tr(C)$ at $t=0$.

Comment: $1$ is the value of $\det(tC+I)$ at $0$. But $tr(C)$ is the value of $\det(tC+I)'$ at $0$.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is the product of all the eigenvalues of a matrix

So, given the eigenvalues of $C$ as $\gamma_i$, $f(t) = \prod t \gamma_i - 1$

The derivative of this expression is

$\dot f(t) = \sum \frac{1}{t \gamma_i - 1} f(t)$

**Note** if the derivative was the trace of $C$ then the determinant would grow linearly with respect to $C$ and that's only true if $C$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Strange answer : You have forgotten 1) to say that you take the logarithm of $\Pi (t\gamma_i-1)$ (please note that I have added parentheses) 2) numerators $\gamma_i$ and 3) the final answer should be simplified (it looks to have forbidden values (poles) in all the $-1/\gamma_i$ whereas it should be a polynomial...).